# How to get the tooltip values from a Dojo pie chart

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Currently, I am testing Charts using Watir-Webdriver.  I can get the text including legends by using the below code:

```
browser.divs(:id=>"charting_Pie").each do |d|
  puts d.text
end
```

What I really need is to get the tool tip values for all the slices.  Also, please help me the same with other charts (Ex:Bar charts).

An example chart can be seen on the [Dojo Charting page](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/charting/demo/monthly-sales-moveslice.php), which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo: Monthly Sales Pie Chart with MoveSlice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/charting/demo/../../../resources/style/demo.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.7/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    <h1>Monthly Sales Pie Chart with MoveSlice</h1>

    <div id="chartNode" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.7/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
    require([
      "dojox/charting/Chart",
      "dojox/charting/themes/Claro",
      "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
      "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
      "dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice",
      "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",
      "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Chart, theme, Pie, Tooltip, MoveSlice) {
      var chartData = [10000,9200,11811,12000,7662,13887,14200,12222,12000,10009,11288,12099];
      var chart = new Chart("chartNode");
      chart.setTheme(theme);
      chart.addPlot("default", {
        type: Pie,
        markers: true,
        radius:170
      });
      chart.addAxis("x");
      chart.addAxis("y", { min: 5000, max: 30000, vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major" });
      chart.addSeries("Monthly Sales - 2010",chartData);
      var tip = new Tooltip(chart,"default");
      var mag = new MoveSlice(chart,"default");
      chart.render();
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which library is "Charts"? As well, can you give an example of the HTML you want to inspect?

Comment: Justin we are using Dojo. Please use the URL:http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/charting/demo/monthly-sales-moveslice.php
I need to get the tooltip  values of all the slices.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using the UI**

For Dojo pie charts, the slices are elements with a tag name of "path". As these are not standard HTML elements, you will have to use Watir's generic `element` method to find them. For example, the first slice would be retrieved by:

```
browser.element(tag_name: 'path')
```

To trigger the tooltip you need to trigger the mouseover event. There are a couple of ways to do this:

```
# Using hover
browser.element(tag_name: 'path').hover

# Using fire_event
browser.element(tag_name: 'path').fire_event('onmouseover')
```

The tooltip text itself appears to be displayed in a div with class dijitTooltipContents:

```
browser.div(class: 'dijitTooltipContents').text
```

Putting it all together, here is a working script:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto('http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/charting/demo/monthly-sales-moveslice.php')
tooltip_text = browser.elements(tag_name: 'path').map do |slice|
    slice.fire_event('onmouseover')
    browser.div(class: 'dijitTooltipContents').text
end
p tooltip_text  
#=> ["10000", "9200", "11811", "12000", "7662", "13887", "14200", "12222", "12000", "10009", "11288", "12099"]
```

From experimentation, I would suggest using the `fire_event` approach instead of `hover`. In this case, `hover` did not trigger quickly enough, which caused inconsistent results such as pulling the same number for multiple slices.

**Inspecting the HTML**

That said, unless you are actually trying to test the functionality of the Dojo pie chart itself, you could just extract the data from the related script elements:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto('http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/charting/demo/monthly-sales-moveslice.php')
script = browser.scripts.find { |script| script.html.include?('chartData') }
tooltip_text = script.html[/chartData\s*=\s*\[([\d,]+)\]/, 1].split(',')
p tooltip_text
#=> ["10000", "9200", "11811", "12000", "7662", "13887", "14200", "12222", "12000", "10009", "11288", "12099"]
```

Comment: Thanks Justin.It works fine.Now am clear with Pie Charts .I have few more Questions.
1.Please tell me how to proceed with Other charts (Ex:Bar Chart) 
2.If I have 2 or more charts in a page,how to automate using the above script.

Comment: Hi @Niresh, I would be happy to help with your other questions, but I would ask that you please only ask one question per question (as per StackOverflow best practices). Please create additional questions for your other questions so that you can show an example page and what you have tried and what you need help with.